# Looking for all possible k values such that a vector is in the span

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Considering the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$, find all values of $k$ such that
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
        2k^2 \\
        -3k \\
        1
        \end{bmatrix} \in \text{ span }
            \left\{
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 \\
                1 \\
                3
            \end{bmatrix},
            \begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                1 \\
                1
            \end{bmatrix},
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 \\
                2 \\
                4
            \end{bmatrix}
            \right\}.
\end{align*}

Here is my approach:
By creating the system of equations
\begin{align*}
        \begin{cases}
            x_1 + x_3 &= 2k^2\\
            x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 &= -3k\\
            3x_1 + x_2 + 4x_3 &= 1
        \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
And then, I acquired its RREF by performing elementary row operations.
\begin{align*}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 & 2k^2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & -2k^2-3k \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -4k^2 + 3k + 1
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Since we get a pivot point at the augmented column,
\begin{align*}
-4k^2+3k+1 &= 0\\
k &= 1, -\dfrac{1}{4}
\end{align*}
I'm not really sure with what I did in the last part. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The given vector space has dimension $2$. On the other hand, according to your reduction,
\begin{align*}
\text{ span }
            \left\{
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 \\
                1 \\
                3
            \end{bmatrix},
            \begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                1 \\
                1
            \end{bmatrix},
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 \\
                2 \\
                4
            \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
        2k^2 \\
        -3k \\
        1
        \end{bmatrix} 
            \right\}
\end{align*}
has dimension $2$ when $-4k^2+3k+1 = 0$ and it has dimension $3$ otherwise.

Comment: According to my understanding, you only take the rows in which the pivot point is the augmented column, is that correct? I was having double thoughts if this logic is right, or I'm supposed to take all rows that have the variable $k$?

Comment: In my opinion your reduction is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In fact your issue can be simplified into

$$\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
        \ \ \ 2k^2 \\
        -3k \\
        1
        \end{bmatrix} \in \text{ span }
            \left\{
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 \\
                1 \\
                3
            \end{bmatrix},
            \begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                1 \\
                1
            \end{bmatrix}
            \right\}.
\end{align*}$$

Indeed the third vector is the sum of the two first ones.

You are now with the system of equations:

$$\begin{align*}
        \begin{cases}
            x_1&&&=& \ \ \ 2k^2\\
            x_1 &+& x_2&=& -3k\\
            3x_1 &+& x_2&=& \ \ \ 1
        \end{cases}
    \end{align*}$$

which can be handled directly without Gauss reduction to the quadratic equation $-4k^2+3k+1 = 0$ you have found by replacing directly $x_1$ by $2k^2$ in the second equation etc..

Comment: So, how do you search for all values of $k$, now that you have that information?

Comment: I solve the quadratic equation to find its roots.